# Deployed EAR is missing in the weblogic console menu

Tags: database, oracle, deployment, weblogic, ear

A weblogic application which is working fine, But on redeploying the .EAR file an error arises mentioning that .EAR file are already existing. On viewing weblogic console menu deployed, It shows no deployed .EAR.

[Missing EAR File from Console Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjqiz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is peculiar, according to you, the application is working fine if that's the case then there should be something deployed on the server, but from the pic, I can't see anything.

- This could probably because of the customize table option, it could be possible that you wouldn't have selected any of the available options.

[image: Available columns and the Chosen columns]

- If this problem arises after redeploying, then there is something wrong with the redeployed `.ear`. If by redeploying, you have just updated the `.ear` then it's mostly a problem with your `.ear`, if you have deleted and re-installed the `.ear` then you should probably check your `config.xml` file before and after the redeploy. And do check for your **server logs** when you are redeploying the `.ear`, that in itself should give a great deal of info.

Please do **update your question with the server logs** so that it would be easy for me (or others) to debug and help you out, and give an appropriate answer.